# How to calculate the van der Waals force from the van der Walls equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

Given the van der Waals equation $$\left(p+\frac{n^2a}{V^2}\right)\left(V-nb\right)=nRT$$
and the van der Waals constants $a$ and $b$, how can I find the van der Walls force between two atoms at distance $d$?

Comment: There's a nice statistical-mechanics derivation on the English Wikipedia entry for the Van-der-Waals equation.

Comment: @Lagerbaer oops, read the wiki page but skipped that part somehow. Thanks!